# Separate polygons based on intersection using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, intersection

I have a PostGIS table of polygons where some intersect with one another.  This is what I'm trying to do:

- For a given polygon selected by id, give me all of the polygons that intersect.  Basically, `select the_geom from the_table where ST_Intersects(the_geom, (select the_geom from the_table where source_id = '123'))`
- From these polygons, I need to create a new polygons such that intersection becomes a new polygon.  So if polygon A intersects with polygon B, I will get 3 new polygons: A minus AB, AB, and B minus AB.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, I think see what you're getting at but a simple graphic might do wonders to help me (and others) see exactly what you want.

Comment: Added some in my answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you said you get a group of intersecting polygons for each polygon you're interested in, you may want to create what is referred to as a "polygon overlay".

This isn't exactly what Adam's solution is doing.  To see the difference, take a look at this picture of an ABC intersection:

[image: ABC intersection]

I believe Adam's solution will create an "AB" polygon that covers both the area of "AB!C" and "ABC", as well as an "AC" polygon that covers "AC!B" and "ABC", and a "BC" polygon that is "BC!A" and "ABC".  So the "AB", "AC", and "BC" output polygons would all overlap the "ABC" area.

A polygon overlay produces non-overlapping polygons, so AB!C would be one polygon and ABC would be one polygon.

Creating a polygon overlay in PostGIS is actually pretty straightforward.

There are basically three steps.

Step 1 is extract the linework [Note that I'm using the [exterior ring](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html) of the polygon, it does get a little more complicated if you want to correctly handle holes]:

```
SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(polygon_col) AS the_geom FROM my_table) AS lines
```

Step 2 is to "node" the linework (produce a node at every intersection).  Some libraries like [JTS](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) have "Noder" classes you can use to do this, but in PostGIS the [ST_Union](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Union.html) function does it for you:

```
SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (...your lines...) AS noded_lines
```

Step 3 is to create all the possible non-overlapping polygons that can come from all those lines, done by the [ST_Polygonize](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Polygonize.html) function:

```
SELECT ST_Polygonize(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (...your noded lines...)
```

You could save the output of each of those steps into a temp table, or you can combine them all into a single statement:

```
CREATE TABLE my_poly_overlay AS
SELECT geom FROM ST_Dump((
    SELECT ST_Polygonize(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (
        SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) AS the_geom FROM (
            SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(polygon_col) AS the_geom FROM my_table) AS lines
        ) AS noded_lines
    )
)
```

I'm using [ST_Dump](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) because the output of ST_Polygonize is a geometry collection, and it is (usually) more convenient to have a table where each row is one of the polygons that makes up the polygon overlay.

Comment: Note that `ST_ExteriorRing` drops any holes. `ST_Boundary` will preserve the interior rings, but it will also create a polygon inside them.

Comment: The union of the exterior rings crashes when there are too many polygons. Unfortunalely this "straightforward" solution works only for small coverages.

Answer (score 13):

If I understand correctly, You want to take (A is the left geometry, B is the right):

[Image of A∪B http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/3996/intersectab1.png](http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/3996/intersectab1.png)

And extract:

A∖AB

[Image of A∖AB http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/273/intersectab2.png](http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/273/intersectab2.png)

AB

[Image of AB http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/7413/intersectab3.png](http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/7413/intersectab3.png)

and B∖AB

[Image of B∖AB http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/5458/intersectab4.png](http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/5458/intersectab4.png)

That is - three different geometries for every intersecting pair.

First, let's create a view of all intersecting geometries. Assuming your table name is `polygons_table`, we will use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW p_intersections AS    -- Create a view with the 
SELECT t1.the_geom as t1_geom,               -- intersecting geoms. Each pair
       t2.the_geom as t2_geom                -- appears once (t2.id<t2.id)
    FROM polygons_table t1, polygons_table t2  
         WHERE t1.id<t2.id AND t1.the_geom && t2.the_geom 
                           AND intersects t1.the_geom, t2.the_geom;
```

Now we have a view (practically, a read-only table) that stores pairs of intersecting geoms, where each pair appears only once due to the `t1.id<t2.id` condition.

Now let's gather your intersections - `A∖AB`,`AB` and `B∖AB`, using SQL's `UNION` on all three queries:

```
--AB:
SELECT ST_intersection(t1.the_geom, t2.the_geom) 
    AS geom 
    FROM p_intersections

UNION 

--A∖AB:
SELECT ST_Difference(t1.the_geom, t2.the_geom) 
    AS geom 
    FROM p_intersections

UNION

--B∖AB:
SELECT ST_Difference(t2.the_geom, t1.the_geom) 
    AS geom 
    FROM p_intersections;
```

Notes:

1. The `&&` operator is used as a filter before the `intersects` operator, to improve performance.
2. I've chosen to create a `VIEW` instead of one gigantic query; This is for convenience only.
3. If you meant `AB` is the union, not the intersection, of `A` and `B` - Use ST_Union instead of st_intersection at the `UNION` query in the appropriate places.
4. The `∖` sign is a unicode sign for Set difference; remove it from the code if it confuses your database.
5. Pictures courtesy of [Wikimedia Commons' nice Set theory category](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).

Comment: My bug ticket on meta: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79/cant-see-images-in-firefox

Comment: Nice explanation! Results are the same as in scw solution, but his way should be faster (does not compute /or store/ additional intersections of A and B)

Comment: Thanks! I think I don't store any extra information, as I only create SQL VIEWs, not tables.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but you compute additional Intersection of A and B, which is not necessery

Comment: This is a great answer and very useful, but not exactly what I was going for.  I apologize if my question was not specific enough.

Comment: Images in this answer don't work anymore.

Answer (score 8):

What you're describing is the way that the [Union operator](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=How%20Union%20%28Analysis%29%20works) works in ArcGIS, but its a little different than either Union or Intersection in the GEOS world. The Shapely manual has [examples of how sets work in GEOS](http://trac.gispython.org/lab/wiki/ShapelyManual#Set-theoreticoperations). However, the PostGIS wiki does have a [good example](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiExamplesOverlayTables) using linework which should do the trick for you.

Alternatively, you could compute three things:

1. ST_Intersection(geom_a, geom_b)
2. ST_Difference(geom_a, geom_b)
3. ST_Difference(geom_b, geom_a)

Those should be the three polygons you mentioned in your second bullet point.

Comment: The PostGIS wiki example is good

Comment: Wouldn't ST_Intersects return boolean if they intersect or not? I think ST_Intersection would work.

Comment: Yeah, typo on my part -- fixed in the original now, thanks Jason!

Answer (score -2):

Something like:

INSERT INTO new_table VALUES((select id, the_geom from old_table where st_intersects(the_geom,(select the_geom from old_table where id='123')) = true

EDIT: you need the actual intersection of the polygon.

INSERT INTO new_table values((select id, ST_Intersection(the_geom,(select the_geom from old where id = 123))

see if that works out.