# Intersection of multiple layers in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection

I need to write PL/pgSQL stored procedure for calculation of intersection of multiple layers. For example, for three layers A, B, C this function should return ABC geometry:
[image]

Function takes as input the id of layers which need to be intersected. Can anyone give me advice for building this function? My thoughts about this I need to intersect first layer and second then result of this intersection intersect with third layer etc.

Comment: Is this question the same as what you are looking for: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/83/97

Comment: No, this is different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give me any comments on my proposed solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fp_intersect(lids varchar)
    RETURNS integer AS
$$
DECLARE
    lid_new  integer;
    lndx     integer := 1;
    lids_arr integer[];
BEGIN

IF regexp_replace(lids, E'\\s+', '', 'g') ~ E'^-?\\d+$' THEN
    RETURN -1;
END IF;

SELECT nextval ('g_layer_lid_seq') INTO lid_new; 

lids_arr := string_to_array(regexp_replace(lids, E'\\s+', '', 'g'), ',');
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_intersect;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_intersect AS SELECT geom FROM g_lgeom WHERE lid = lids_arr[1];

WHILE lndx < array_length(lids_arr, 1) LOOP
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS SELECT ST_Intersection(geom, g_next) AS geom
    FROM tmp_intersect
    JOIN (
        SELECT geom AS g_next
        FROM g_lgeom
        WHERE lid = lids_arr[lndx+1]
    ) AS _
    ON ST_Intersects(geom, g_next);
    lndx := lndx+1;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_intersect;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_intersect AS SELECT geom FROM tmp;
END LOOP;

INSERT INTO g_lgeom(lid, geom) SELECT lid_new, (_.p_geom).geom FROM (SELECT ST_Dump(geom) AS p_geom FROM tmp_intersect) AS _;

RETURN lid_new;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```