# Polygon overlay with Shapely

Tags: python, polygon-creation, shapely

I'm trying to capture all the non-overlapping polygons indicated below using Shapely (given polygons A,B & C).  Moreover, I'm hoping to do so without iteration, testing for intersect etc. The accepted answer to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83/separate-polygons-based-on-intersection-using-postgis) question expresses the PostGIS method but it would seem that 'union' means different things to different people.

[image: polygon overlay]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to iterate at some level. (*Update*: I've edited to remove all "for" loops, except for one [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

```
# imports used throughout this example
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from itertools import combinations

# Here are your input shapes (circles A, B, C)
A = Point(3, 6).buffer(4)
B = Point(6, 2).buffer(4)
C = Point(1, 2).buffer(4)

# list the shapes so they are iterable
shapes = [A, B, C]
```

First you need the union of all intersections (use a [cascaded union](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#cascading-unions)), using the [combination](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) pair of each shape. Then you remove (via `difference`) the intersections from the union of all shapes.

```
# All intersections
inter = cascaded_union([pair[0].intersection(pair[1]) for pair in combinations(shapes, 2)])
# Remove from union of all shapes
nonoverlap = cascaded_union(shapes).difference(inter)
```

Here is what `nonoverlap` looks like (via JTS Test Builder):
[image: nonoverlap]

Answer (score 2):

After a few years there seems to be a better solution through `shapely`:

```
# imports used throughout this example
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import polygonize, unary_union

# Here are your input shapes (circles A, B, C)
A = Point(3, 6).buffer(4)
B = Point(6, 2).buffer(4)
C = Point(1, 2).buffer(4)
...

# list the shapes so they are iterable
shapes = [A, B, C, ...]

# generate the overlay
list(polygonize(unary_union(list(x.exterior for x in shapes))))
```

It supports any lenght of geometry, the only problem it's about the calculation time, and not supporting polygon with holes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think your solution is better than the one by @MikeT? I can only read about a problem in terms of calculation times.