# polygon map overlay algorithm

Tags: vector, geometry, algorithm, overlay

There are many algorithms for binary map overlay operation in vector data format which take two layers of map and produce resultant layer i.e overlaid layer as output.
I am wondering whether there are any algorithms which take more than two layers say 3 layers simultaneously and produce the overlay result?

Answer (score 4):

The low-level spatial predicate operators are all binary—i.e., compare geometry A to geometry B. For example, see the [DE-9IM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) topological model, which is the basis for *Intersects*, *Contains*, etc. When you have more than two, say geometry C, then you might need to compare the [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of geometries: AB, AC, BC. But it all really depends on what you are trying to determine.

For a specific coded example of how you handle more than two geometries, see [Polygon overlay with Shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11987/polygon-overlay-with-shapely/11990#11990). This example also features a *cascaded union*, which unions several (more than two) geometries, so I guess is a good example of an efficient map algorithm that take takes more than two inputs.