# Getting intersection of multiple polygons efficiently in Python

Tags: python, polygon, intersection, polygon-creation, shapely

I would like to get the intersection of multiple polygons. Using Python's `shapely` package, I can find the intersection of two polygons using the [`intersection`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.intersection) function. Is there a similar efficient function for obtaining the intersection of multiple polygons?

Here is a code snippet to understand what I mean:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

coord1 = ( 0,0 )
point1 = Point(coord1)
circle1 = point1.buffer(1)

coord2 = ( 1,1 )
point2 = Point(coord2)
circle2 = point2.buffer(1)

coord3 = ( 1,0 )
point3 = Point(coord3)
circle3 = point3.buffer(1)
```

An intersection of two circles can be found by `circle1.intersection(circle2)`. I can find the intersection of all three circles by `circle1.intersection(circle2).intersection(circle3)`. However, this approach is not salable to a large number of polygons as it requires increasingly more code. I would like a function that takes an arbitrary number of polygons and returns their intersection.

Comment: im thinking maybe store the coords in a dictionary and loop through it while using from itertools import combinations. I will post soon

Comment: What do you mean by "their intersections"? Do you mean all areas that intersect with at least one other polygon, or the areas that *all* the inputs intersect?

Comment: I mean the intersection of all polygons, not at least one.

Comment: You should clarify this above (perhaps with an example output). I'm fairly certain most of the answers *don't* behave as you wish. (And the fact several answerers have misunderstood is evidence enough that the question needs clarification.)

Comment: Also, for a large number of geometries, you will want to consider how likely it is they all even *have* a common intersection. If it's unlikely they all intersect, consider [using an rtree](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/05/12/using-rtree-spatial-indexing-with-ogr/) to optimize intersections away. In that case, this could avoid taking *any* intersections in many cases.

Comment: Thank you @jpmc26 I will look into it and edit. Also the `rtree` is a good tip.

Comment: @jpmc26 I've just added an update to my answer where rtree is used. The approach is more efficient and scalable now. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

One possible approach could be considering the combination of pairs of polygons, their intersections and finally the union of all the intersections via a cascaded union (like suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11990/22405)):

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from itertools import combinations

circles = [
    Point(0,0).buffer(1),
    Point(1,0).buffer(1),
    Point(1,1).buffer(1),
]

intersection = cascaded_union(
    [a.intersection(b) for a, b in combinations(circles, 2)]
)
print intersection
```

---

A more efficient approach should use a spatial index, like [Rtree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/), in order to deal with a lot of geometries (not the case of the three circles):

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from rtree import index

circles = [
    Point(0,0).buffer(1),
    Point(1,0).buffer(1),
    Point(1,1).buffer(1),
]
intersections = []
idx = index.Index()

for pos, circle in enumerate(circles):
    idx.insert(pos, circle.bounds)

for circle in circles:
    merged_circles = cascaded_union([circles[pos] for pos in idx.intersection(circle.bounds) if circles[pos] != circle])
    intersections.append(circle.intersection(merged_circles))

intersection = cascaded_union(intersections)
print intersection
```

Comment: I don't believe this does what the OP wants. It gives back the areas that *at least 2* polygons cover, whereas the OP is only looking for areas covered by *all* the polygons in the set. See clarification in comments.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a iteration or recursivity?
something like :

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

def intersection(circle1, circle2):
    return circle1.intersection(circle2)

coord1 = ( 0,0 )
point1 = Point(coord1)
circle1 = point1.buffer(1)

coord2 = ( 1,1 )
point2 = Point(coord2)    
circle2 = point2.buffer(1)


coord3 = ( 1,0 )
point3 = Point(coord3)
circle3 = point3.buffer(1)
circles = [circle1, circle2, circle3]
intersectionResult = None

for j, circle  in enumerate(circles[:-1]):

    #first loop is 0 & 1
    if j == 0:
        circleA = circle
        circleB = circles[j+1]
     #use the result if the intersection
    else:
        circleA = intersectionResult
        circleB = circles[j+1]
    intersectionResult = intersection(circleA, circleB)

result= intersectionResult
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this code a shot. its pretty simple in concept and I believe gets you what you are looking for.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from itertools import combinations
dic ={}
dic['coord1']=Point(0,0).buffer(1)
dic['coord2']=Point(1,1).buffer(1)
dic['coord3']=Point(1,0).buffer(1)
inter = {k[0]+v[0]:k[1].intersection(v[1]) for k,v in combinations(dic.items(),2)}
print inter
```

and if you want the output to be stored as a shapefile use fiona:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point,mapping
import fiona
from itertools import combinations
schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': {'Place': 'str'}}
dic ={}
dic['coord1']=Point(0,0).buffer(1)
dic['coord2']=Point(1,1).buffer(1)
dic['coord3']=Point(1,0).buffer(1)
inter = {k[0]+v[0]:k[1].intersection(v[1]) for k,v in combinations(dic.items(),2)}
print inter
with fiona.open(r'C:\path\abid', "w", "ESRI Shapefile", schema) as output:
    for x,y in inter.items():
        output.write({'properties':{'Place':x},'geometry':mapping(y)})
```

this outputs -

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this does what the OP wants. It gives back the areas that *at least 2* polygons cover, whereas the OP is only looking for areas covered by *all* the polygons in the set. See clarification in comments. Additionally, `k` and `v` are poor choices for variable names in your `dict` comprehensions. Those variables each refer to different elements of `dic.items()`, not a key-value pair. Something like `a, b` would be less misleading.

Comment: ohh okay yeah I did not understand what he meant

Comment: and point well taken about my k,v choices--i just automatically use k,v when looping through a dictionary..didnt give it much thought