# Create Polygon Overlay Handling Holes

Tags: postgis-2.0, windows-server-2008

How can I create a polygon overlay that correctly handles holes? [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/785/8548) provides a method of creating a polygon overlay that does not handle holes. Can it be modified to correctly handle holes?

Software Versions:

- PostgreSQL 9.2.1
- PostGIS 2.0.1 r9979
- Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: use ST_MakePolygon http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_MakePolygon.html

Comment: I don't think that's correct. When a polygon has holes, another polygon can fall into the area of the whole, and that should result in a polygon inside the area of the hole. The function you recommend is for generating polygons that contain holes. That will not help in the case I describe.